# login function rendering first letter only

Tags: php, function, session, authentication

I have just made the login function and it is working alright;

however the name is not shows correctly; for some reason it only echoes the first letter of the name, J. instead if Jack:

It is written alright in the database.

```
echo "You are now logged in , {$_SESSION['name']}";
```

Has anyone ever encountered the same problem?

Regards

Jacek

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "You are now logged in , {$_SESSION[name]}";
```

Don't use quotes around `name`. They are not necessary inside a double quoted string to access an array element.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($_SESSION["name"])`?

Comment: i've already figured it out; changed my code and now it's working alright. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just thought i might add more code to make the problem a bit more clear:

here the function check_login checks if the result is in the database and passes it on to another file:

```
function check_login($db, $email = '', $pass='')
{
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))
{
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
$r=$db->query($sql);
$num=$r->num_rows;
if($num != 0)
{
$row=$r->fetch_assoc();
return array (true, $row['name']);

 }
else
{
    echo "Your login details are incorrect. Please try again.";
}

}
}
```

In another file:

```
list($check,$data) = check_login($db, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

if($check)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
redirect_user('the_stoles/loggedin.php');
}
else
{
    echo "Your login details are incorrect. Please try again.";
}
```

ane finally:

session_start();

```
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
                {
                    require('login_functions.php');
                    redirect_user();
                }
                else
                {
                echo "You are now logged in, {$_SESSION['name']}";
                }
```

I hope i made it a bit clearer and someone might get a clue.

Cheers in advance
Jacek